# C# WPF When drag and dropping how do I make a copy of the UIElement that is being dragged

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, copy

I am really new at C# WPF. I am making a program that allows users to drag and drop elements to create a custom weighted graph but I do not know how to make a copy.

I do not know where to start. [Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOwrw.png) [After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xajWp.png) But I don't know how to make a copy of the node and also making the new copied node a unique element.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Simulation.View.Display.Content.GraphCreation
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for DragItems.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class DragItems : UserControl
    {
        public DragItems()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void NodeCircle_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                DragDrop.DoDragDrop(nodeCircle, new DataObject(DataFormats.Serializable, nodeCircle), DragDropEffects.Move);
            }
        }
        private void iconCanvas1_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            Point dropPosition = e.GetPosition(iconCanvas1);
            Canvas.SetLeft(nodeCircle, dropPosition.X);
            Canvas.SetTop(nodeCircle, dropPosition.Y);
        }

        private void iconCanvas1_DragLeave(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.OriginalSource == iconCanvas1)
            {
                object data = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Serializable);
                if (data is UIElement element)
                {
                    iconCanvas1.Children.Remove(element);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My current drag and drop code.